# How to reinstate auto increment during importation of CSV file into MySql while retaining pervious numbering?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, auto-increment

```
ID,CREATED,FILENUMBER,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,ZIP

1008,"02/27/2014, 10:28",142840,124 North St,Anycity,NY,91111

1007,"02/12/2014, 21:06",142839,424 Maple Ave,Anycity,NY,91111

1006,"02/12/2014, 21:06",142839,143 Great Pl,Anycity,NY,91111
```

I have "like above" records in the comma separated value file format. I would like to import this table into MySQL and while doing so to:

retain existing records with same ID numbers
to make ID to continue increment with each record added
if one of the records is is deleted I don't want records to update their number (for example, if record with ID 1007 is deleted the remaining record numbers would 1006 and 1008)
And the last, but not least I would like "FILENUMBER"  to Auto increment on each new record
with first two numbers being the year date (e.g. 14 stands for 2014) and the remaining
four numbers are just incrementing with each record (e.g 142841, 142842, 142843, etc). Another example, if record is added December 31, 2014, the file number should auto increment with like 142844 and any next record addition on January 1, 2015 it would be 152845.
and I also want retain each existing records same FILENUMBER numbers and then with new records continue to auto increment.

Is there a way to import this into MySQL and to make columns ID and FILENUMBER to do the above?

I am thinking of something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `records` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `CREATED` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
  `FILENUMBER` int(6) zerofill not null auto_increment, 
  `ADDRESS` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `STATE` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `ZIP` INT(10) NOT NULL);




load data local infile 'c:\\records.csv' 
into table records 
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(ID, CREATED, FILENUMBER, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Some corrections***:

You can't define multiple fields to have auto increment.
If you want to keep `id` with `auto...`, then `filenumber int ... auto...` is wrong.

***Possible options*** (for enabling):

1. You better not define auto increment for `filenumber` field but for
   `id` field only.
2. For the latest inserted `filenumber` value to hold current `year` as
   prefix, then you need a `trigger` to set the 2 digit year as
   *prefix*.
3. You can use primary key value as suffix with year to form the
   `filenumber`.

And, to retain the former auto_increment value in the new table into which you are importing data, you need to use `alter table` command.

```
alter table table_name 
  auto_increment = new_number_from_where_to_start_with;
```

Comment: Ravinder, with your alter table suggestion you have solved my id column numbering. It will now continue to increment automatically upon each new record insertion with the correct numbers. However, due to my very limited knowledge of MySql (and SQL overall), I have no clue on how to set filenumber column to prefix and suffix upon new record insertion automatically. I'd like to be able to manually enter values in all other columns, but id and filenumber columns have to be updated with correct values itself, though for id column the problem is already solved.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Look into 2nd possible option I suggested in my answer.